# how to get a member with maximum (or minimum ) score from redis sorted set given a subset of members?

Tags: redis, sortedset

I am writing a algo for deducing the user with the least amount of work load. Based on the type/complexity of the tasks being created, i narrow down on the list of the users that are capable of performing it. Now, I need to find the user who has the least number tasks currently assigned to him/her.
I am using redis sorted set to store the members/users along the score indicating the number of the tasks assigned to them.
Is there a way to get a member with least score given a subset of members?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Member with minimum score:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE myset -inf +inf WITHSCORES LIMIT 0 1
```

Member with maximum score:

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE myset +inf -inf WITHSCORES LIMIT 0 1
```

Comment: What is the time complexity on these operations? Docs say O(log(N)+M), does the limit lazily evaluate to give better performance?

Comment: It's `O(log(N))`, so for 1 billion entries it's about 20 comparisons http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(1bln)

Comment: Adding for completeness: `ZREVRANGE 0 0 WTHSCORES` for maximum score, and `ZRANGE 0 0 WITHSCORES` for minimum score

Answer (score 4):

**Sorted set element with lowest score:**
`ZRANGE key 0 0 WITHSCORES`

**Sorted set element with highest score:**
`ZREVRANGE key 0 0 WITHSCORES`

> Time complexity: O(log(N)+M) with N being the number of elements in
>   the sorted set and M the number of elements returned.

**Docs:** https://redis.io/commands/zrange; https://redis.io/commands/zrevrange

Answer (score 0):

Hope, i understand the structure of your sorted set:

```
members/users => score
```

So you have some different ways to solve your question. But there is no solution for make this on one redis command.

1. Catch data with set of `ZSCORE` calls. PHP with phpredis lib sample with O(N) complexity.

   ```
   $subsetOfUsers = ['user1', 'user2'];
   $multi = $redis->multi(); 
   foreach ($subsetOfUsers as $user) {
      $redis->zScore('yourKey', $user);
   }
   $result = $multi->exec();
   ```
2. Using [`ZINTERSTORE`](http://redis.io/commands/zinterstore). Add your subset of members to temportary sorted set with `ZADD` and `ZINTERSTORE` temp sorted set with your sorted set. Next get your results with `ZRANGE`. This can be executed with `MULTI`.

   ```
   ADD tmp 0 "user1"
   ADD tmp 0 "user2"
   ZINTERSTORE out 2 tmp yourDataSortedSetKey
   ZRANGE out 0 -1 WITHSCORES
   ```

   It`s a clear "redis way" with O(N*K) + O(M*log(M)) algorithmic complexity.

p.s. If you are using redis >= 2.6 you can write LUA stored procudure for optimize both of given samples.